# How can I set cookies of another page in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, cookies, setcookie, cookiestore

I'm having trouble with my project. 
My attempt is to programmatically log in a website by using `HttpWebRequest` from my site. After that, I uses `CookieContainer` to collect all the returned cookies, and uses them to scrape data from that website.

Everything ran fine.

Now I want to set the cookies to the browser so that another users can use the cookies too. What should I do to save the `CookieContainer` to the browser?

Comment: I retagged this to asp.net because of the title, but it was retagged back to classic. Which is it?

Comment: What language are you using? classic-asp or asp.net?

Comment: @Ben CookieContainer is definitely not classic-asp but belongs to the System.Net namespace